# TortoiseSVN Show Log and Repository Browser colors

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have access to two different repositories. When I'm using Show Log or Repository Browser functionalities of TortoiseSVN, the colors on taskbar are different for the repositories. What do those colors mean? I'm quite sure they are not related with local changes.

[image: colors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a visual clue to distinguish dialogues that belong to the same repository, but the colours themselves do not have any special meaning.

This is documented under the `GroupTaskbarIconsPerRepoOverlay` [advanced setting](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-registry):

> If this option is set to true, then every icon on the Win7 taskbar shows a small colored rectangle overlay, indicating the repository the dialogs/windows are used for.